# scp -r does not seem to work on zsh, no idea why

Tags: zsh, scp

I can scp files to a remote host, but if I try to `scp -r` a directory it does not work

```
scp -r mydir me@remote.host:/where/the/dir/has/to/go/
scp: realpath /whatever/mydir: No such file
scp: upload "/whatever/mydir": path canonicalization failed
scp: failed to upload directory cf2t to /where/the/dir/has/to/go/
```

I thought it was some issue with globbing, so I quoted different parts of the damn command to no avail.

Comment: Does `realpath mydir` give any errors or do anything funny?

Comment: Nope.  There are no symlinks or anything else.

Comment: Is your `scp` really what you think, or maybe an alias or shell function? Do a `type -a scp`. Aside from this, your command does not use anything tricky specific to zsh. In particular you don't do any globbing, and as long as the path does not have spaces or other characters specific to the shell, you don't need to quote anything. With this type of error, you better post the **exact** path name which you have used.

Comment: `type -a scp`
    `scp is an alias for noglob scp_wrap`
    `scp is /usr/bin/scp`

Comment: I've noticed this issue as well after the latest MacOS upgrade (not sure that's the cause).

Comment: Same issue on bash, Manjaro Linux. But I can scp -r remote to local

Answer (score 1):

1. on `remote.host`: `mkdir -p /where/the/dir/has/to/go/`
2. on local host: `scp -r mydir me@remote.host:/where/the/dir/has/to/go/`

Answer (score 1):

When trying to scp a directory to a raspberry pi via scp with an ssh key, I would put in `scp -i ~/.ssh/ssh_filename -r directoryname pi@192.168.22.1:/home/pi`. It would return `scp: realpath /home/pi/directoryname: No such file`.

What this means is it **looks for a directory of the same name at the destination**, because it won't make a directory for you when you scp. At one point it would, but not anymore. Just make that directory at the destination. After that, you can scp and transfer the directory contents.

Alternatively, you could just zip the file, nix the `-r`, and unzip it once it arrives. `unzip directoryname.zip`

Comment: But but but I did make a directory with scp just this morning (Linux to Linux, no idea what version of scp)